# Rake ActionMailer issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I'm troubleshooting my application to understand why emails fail through Rake.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def User.test
    puts "a string is returned"
    UserMailer.email_test
  end
end
```

My UserMailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def email_test
    mail to: "test", subject: "test"
  end
end
```

If I call the method from the rails console (User.test) I obtain the correct output:

```
a string is returned
Rendered user_mailer/email_test.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.8ms)
Rendered user_mailer/email_test.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.2ms)

UserMailer#email_test: processed outbound mail in 106.5ms
=> #<Mail::Message:69873560567220, Multipart: true, <To: test>, <Subject: test>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_55c7b5db58f18_16fd3f8cb2e279986086"; charset=UTF-8>>
```

Now I am trying to move this in a rake task in a lib/tasks/scheduler.rake file as follows:

```
task :mytest => :environment do
  User.test
end
```

When I call the task using

```
rake mytest
```

The only item I get returned is the string but nothing related to the email (see below).

```
bastien@bastien-ThinkPad-T540p:~/rails/app-505/lib/tasks$ rake mytest
(in /home/bastien/rails/app-505)
a string is returned
bastien@bastien-ThinkPad-T540p:~/rails/app-505/lib/tasks$
```

Comment: Use `binding.pry` before `UserMailer.email_test` in your User.test class method. And then try to call the `UserMailer.email_test` method from the pry console while running the rake task. See if it shows any error or you can get any clue from there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't get debug messages when running rake tasks, so the email is probably being generated successfully. The only problem I've found is that you're not using the `deliver` method in the generated email, so it's not being delivered. You need to run `UserMailer.email_test.deliver` to send it. To be sure that everything is working, I suggest that you install the [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem in the development environment, which opens up the email in a web browser tab.